# Use Microsoft Band SDK in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, microsoft-band

Is it possible to use the Microsoft Band SDK in Unity 3D? I haven't heard any official word on it and I'm wondering if this is something we are waiting on Microsoft to get around to or if both companies have to work closely together to accomplish this. Due to the way Unity builds your project data to specific platforms, I highly doubt you could simply add the SDK to your project through Visual Studio and actually make use of it. I am writing C# scripts which are compiled by Unity. I want to take accelerometer readings and place a tile on the Band to interact with the app, and I want to build my project to UWP and Android, and iOS if possible.

Comment: Some libs does actually work in Unity by Visual Studio refs ; but most of the time it is better to actually place .Net DLL direcly in the Unity project. Give a shot and you will see

Comment: You'll need to be much more specific about how you intend to use the Band within your Unity application.  For example, is it a cross-platform application, a Windows universal application, are you using C# or native C++, etc.  That will help determine what options you have to integrate with the Band.

Comment: @PhilHoff--MSFT I've edited the question to explain this.

Comment: @OwenD. since I am searching for the same thing, did you manage to find a solution to this?

Comment: @JoseRamon No, Band support is not critical to my game and I'm on a deadline so I've stopped looking into it for now.

Comment: @JoseRamon I'm watching [this page](https://www.facebook.com/ADropInTheDigitalOcean/?fref=nf) as it sounds like he may make a plugin available soon. [Here's the blog post](http://www.dyadica.co.uk/microsoft-band-unity3d/) showing off a preview

Comment: It seems like this guy pulled it off: http://www.cenito.se/2015/07/band-racer-a-microsoft-band-and-windows-phone-game/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Band SDK targets native Android, iOS, and Windows so you won't get support within Unity 3D "for free".  There are [Xamarin bindings](https://github.com/mattleibow/Microsoft-Band-SDK-Bindings) for the Band SDK that allow its use cross-platform in Xamarin-based apps.  You *may* be able to use these bindings to use a Band within Unity either directly, or indirectly by creating a plugin which wraps them.  If not, you *may* still be able to create a native Unity plugin that wraps use of the native SDKs on each of the platforms you intend to support.

Answer (score 1):

Unity 3D support is not available in the current Microsoft Band SDK. You can add a feature request at the User Voice page (http://microsofthealth.uservoice.com/forums/283636-microsoft-health-and-microsoft-band) to have it considered for future releases.